# Thread safety of Saxon 9 Compiled Transform

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, saxon

Using Saxon 9 HE, it takes a few seconds to compile style sheet (in .Net).

Can any one verify that compiled transform is thread safe. i.e. If i compile style sheet and hold onto the instance to invoke in future. Will invoking this compiled Transform instance simultaneously from multiple thread cause any issue?

```
XsltTransformer transformer = proc.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri("file:///" + styleSheet)).Load();

//Store transformer instance as class variable and reuse it to eliminate compilation time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation on saxonica.com](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api/XsltExecutable), you only need to compile once `XsltExecutable ex = proc.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri("file:///" + styleSheet));` and can then use the `XsltExecutable` in several threads: "An XsltExecutable is immutable, and therefore thread-safe.".

About `XsltTransformer`, [it says](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api/XsltTransformer) "An XsltTransformer should not be used concurrently in multiple threads. It is safe, however, to reuse the object within a single thread to run the same stylesheet several times.".